# Can I disable the lighted Apple logo on the back of my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to disable the light on the apple behind my screen. Besides covering it physically, is there a program or setting to disable it?

Reason being - to make my MacBook Pro as uninteresting as possible to hyperactive two-year-olds.

Comment: Duct tape fixes everything :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nope.

The glowing Apple on your MacBook Pro is actually illuminated by the backlight of your screen as well. So you can't turn it off as long as you have your screen lighted on. Your best bet is probably to put a sticker on it.

Comment: or a case (which might be good idea with that hyperactive two-year old anyway)

Comment: I actually came across this question because the stupid light is showing though my sticker.  :< makes me angry.

Comment: Double (or triple) sticker could help with that :)

Comment: Or better yet, fix a piece of opaque material that obscures the logo underneath your sticker. I used a small square of metal foil.

Comment: If you are having trouble with the light shining through the sticker, use a piece of Aluminum Foil Tape -- it will block all the light perfectly. It's what I use.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible. The Apple logo (at least on a MacBook Air and the two previous Apple laptops I owned) is lit by the backlight of your screen. (Try changing your screen brightness, and you'll see the brightness of the Apple logo change as well.) I think covering it would be your only option.

Answer (score 3):

If you can google around a bit, i recall seeing stickers that can be applied to the **inside** of the MacBooks white plastic apple logo, to give it different appearances. I'm sure you can cover it up with an opaque material like thick paper to keep it from glowing, but to keep it as clean looking as possible on the outside.

Comment: nice - thinking outside the box there (actually inside the case). I don't think I am going to be ordering anything - was hoping for software solution. However, the perfect solution would be something on the inside of the case, which could be made opaque via a switch, or sliding into place upon command somehow.

Comment: well this would be quite permanent, like a sticker. At least you can stop the light with black construction paper or something, without ruining the ouside