# Disable oscillating light on MacBook Pro when in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro

This is not the same question as [Can I disable the lighted Apple logo on the back of my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48594/can-i-disable-the-lighted-apple-logo-on-the-back-of-my-macbook-pro)

When I shut the lid of my macbook pro, it goes into sleep mode.  When it is in sleep mode, there is a small oscillating white light on the front of it.

[image: Like so]

That small pill-capsule-like shape on the long metal strip glows forever on end when in sleep mode.  Is there any way to disable this while keeping the computer in sleep mode?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @MacLemon — To sleep, maybe. Like the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Put a piece of cardboard in front.

I have tested and approved this solution.

As far as I know, this is the only non-destructive solution.

Answer (score 3):

On the model shown your best bet is to disconnect the light from inside the case. Also depending on the model, you may lose the IR receiver and battery level indicator as well.

Or if you don't want to disconnect the cable, you could have a physical barrier - some aluminum tape (actual aluminum, not grey/silver plastic) when cut to shape should stick there for some time and blend in somewhat better than other tapes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the lid open so the ambient light sensors get a reading. They will adjust the brightness accordingly in a dark room but not completely turn it off.

Changing power management setting from sleep to hibernation (suspend to disk) should turn it off completely at the cost of having to wait for writing the sleepimage file when closing and reading it into memory when waking up.

Answer (score 0):

the best and the safest solution is to use deep sleep widget https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/deepsleep.html

Comment: Deep Sleep put a computer in hibernation, which isn't the same as the default sleep. [More info here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1053471/sleepmode.html).